# Cannot assign property "FontFamily": Property does not exist

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi new to style for Xamarin.forms. I have this old xamarin.forms app, I do a debug and I got this error for below Style inside App.xaml

problem: Position 39:17. Cannot assign property "FontFamily": Property does not exist, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property

Please help.

```
    <!--  Application resource dictionary  -->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!--  colors  -->
        <!--<Color x:Key="HeaderTextColor">#585858</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BodyTextColor">#C3C3C3</Color>-->

        <Color x:Key="TimelineColor">#E4B6C3</Color>
        <Color x:Key="HeaderTextColor">#3C3C3C</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BodyTextColor">#869EAC</Color>
        <Color x:Key="TimeColor">#A64C79</Color>

        <!--  font families  -->
        <OnPlatform
            x:Key="RegularFontFamily"
            x:TypeArguments="x:String"
            Android="sans-serif"
            iOS="HelveticaNeue" />
        <OnPlatform
            x:Key="LightFontFamily"
            x:TypeArguments="x:String"
            Android="sans-serif-light"
            iOS="HelveticaNeue-Light" />
        <OnPlatform
            x:Key="MediumFontFamily"
            x:TypeArguments="x:String"
            Android="sans-serif-medium"
            iOS="HelveticaNeue-Medium" />

        <!--  fonts  -->
        <Font
            x:Key="HeaderFont"
            FontFamily="{StaticResource MediumFontFamily}"
            FontSize="30" />
        <Font
            x:Key="SubHeaderFont"
            FontFamily="{StaticResource MediumFontFamily}"
            FontSize="18" />
        <Font
            x:Key="TitleFont"
            FontFamily="{StaticResource MediumFontFamily}"
            FontSize="20" />
        <Font
            x:Key="BodyFont"
            FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFontFamily}"
            FontSize="18" />


        <!--  styles  -->
        <Style x:Key="PageHeaderLabel" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource HeaderTextColor}" />
            <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource HeaderFont}" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="SubHeaderLabel" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource BodyTextColor}" />
            <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource SubHeaderFont}" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ClassTimeLabel" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource TimeColor}" />
            <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource TitleFont}" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ClassNameLabel" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource HeaderTextColor}" />
            <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource TitleFont}" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ClassInstructorLabel" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource BodyTextColor}" />
            <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource BodyFont}" />
        </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

//--- Update : I changed this part : I still got error

```
           <ResourceDictionary>

        <Color x:Key="BodyTextColor">#C3C3C3</Color>-->

        <Color x:Key="TimelineColor">#E4B6C3</Color>
        <Color x:Key="HeaderTextColor">#3C3C3C</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BodyTextColor">#869EAC</Color>
        <Color x:Key="TimeColor">#A64C79</Color>

       <OnPlatform
            x:Key="RegularFontFamily"
            x:TypeArguments="x:String"
            Android="sans-serif"
            iOS="HelveticaNeue" />
        <OnPlatform
            x:Key="LightFontFamily"
            x:TypeArguments="x:String"
            Android="sans-serif-light"
            iOS="HelveticaNeue-Light" />
        <OnPlatform
            x:Key="MediumFontFamily"
            x:TypeArguments="x:String"
            Android="sans-serif-medium"
            iOS="HelveticaNeue-Medium" />


        <x:Double x:Key="HeaderFontSize">30</x:Double>
        <x:Double x:Key="SubHeaderFontSize">18</x:Double>
        <x:Double x:Key="BodyFontSize">18</x:Double>
         <x:Double x:Key="TitleFontSize">20</x:Double>



        <Style x:Key="PageHeaderLabel" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource HeaderTextColor}" />
            <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource HeaderFont}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource HeaderFontSize}" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="SubHeaderLabel" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource BodyTextColor}" />
            <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource SubHeaderFont}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource SubHeaderFontSize}" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ClassTimeLabel" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource TimeColor}" />
            <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource TitleFont}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource TitleFontSize}" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ClassNameLabel" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource HeaderTextColor}" />
            <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource TitleFont}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource TitleFontSize}" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ClassInstructorLabel" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource BodyTextColor}" />
            <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource BodyFont}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource BodyFontSize}" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="TitleFont" TargetType="Label">
           <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource HeaderTextColor}" />
           <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource MediumFontFamily}" />
          <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource TitleFontSize}" />
       </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close, however instead of `Font` use `Double` to define `FontSize`, example:

```
<OnPlatform
    x:Key="MediumFontFamily"
    x:TypeArguments="x:String"
    Android="sans-serif-medium"
    iOS="HelveticaNeue-Medium" />
```

Now you should define the specific size:

```
<x:Double x:Key="TitleFontSize">20</x:Double>
```

Next consume it:

```
<Style x:Key="TitleFont" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource HeaderTextColor}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MediumFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource TitleFontSize}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: I m a bit lost. Do I remove all the <font> in Fonts section or I just remove the size which declare in the font? Can you show me how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Replace all <Font ... /> by <x:Double ... /> and specify the FontSize in Style, exactly like I demonstrated in the answer. Its quite simple once you get it.

Comment: I still got error. Please correct my mistakes. like mismatch HeaderFont. Why?

Comment: I updated my answer. Beside that the problem is obvious, inside <Style ..> you have to pay attention to the setter of "Font": #1 it should be "FontFamily", #2 it should point to existing resources. Currently some still point to old "Font" definitions like "HeaderFont".

Comment: Just Updated. To avoid any mistake on my part. Can you correct my mistake and make a style and paste it here so I can copy and paste it in my project. I am quite new to this syntax. You mean I shoud not use Font =? use Fontname instead?

Comment: I already provided a working example that you can reuse. Also, please check my previous comment. If you are getting lost, do it step by step. Define only one font, check if it works, then next ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="default-font">
  <On Platform="Android" Value="sans-serif-medium" />
  <On Platform="iOS" Value="sans-serif-medium" />
</OnPlatform>
```